# Как корректно передать данные из std.ArrayList в Slice?

Tags: массивы, структуры, zig

Столкнулся со странным поведением структуры в zig. Точнее слайса (*[]const u8*) являющегося одним из элементов структуры, ниже пример.

```
const Statement = struct {
content: []const u8,
};

// read file
var script_file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile("text.txt", .{});
defer script_file.close();

// allocator
var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
defer _ = gpa.deinit();
const allocator = gpa.allocator();

// Read the text file by line
var buf_reader = std.io.bufferedReader(script_file.reader());
const reader = buf_reader.reader();

var line = std.ArrayList(u8).init(allocator);
defer line.deinit();

var line_no: usize = 0;
var statements: [26]Statement = undefined;  // в файле фиксированное количество строк

while (reader.streamUntilDelimiter(line.writer(), '\n', null)) : (line_no += 1) {
    defer line.clearRetainingCapacity();

    var i: u16 = 0;

    // write content in statments
    for (line.items) |char| {
        if (char == ' ') {
            statements[line_no] = .{ .content = line.items[(i + 1)..] };
            break;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    std.debug.print("State content -- {d}:\t {s}\n", .{ line_no, statements[line_no].content });  // тут statements[line_no].content выводит корректно
} else |err| switch (err) {
    error.EndOfStream => {}, // Continue on
    else => std.debug.print("Ошибка при построчном чтении файла... {any}", .{err}), // Print error
}

inline for (statements) |s| {
    std.debug.print("State content len: {d}\n", .{s.content.len}); // корректно печатает длину слайса
    std.debug.print("State content ptr: {any}\n", .{s.content.ptr});  // печатает указатель на слайс
    std.debug.print("State content: {s}\n", .{s.content});    // здесь происходит ошибка:
    // State content: thread 13433 panic: reached unreachable code

}
```

Т.е. компиляция проходит успешно, но обратиться к элементу структуры вне цыкла в котором были перенесины данные не получается. При том длину строки отображает корректно. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с таким?
Версия zig - 0.12.0-dev.2341+92211135f.